# Email Service creating FeedPost not sending notification

Tags: chatter, apex-email-service

I have a chatter group who members are set to receive notifications upon every chatter post.

If I create a feeditem post via the UI or via APEX the users immediately get a email notification of the group post activity.

- Issue is: Have created an APEX Email Service which creates a chatter feed for this group.  When the feedpost is created via the Email Service the group notification is not being sent out to the group members.

Have verified that the Email Service user has permission to create the chatter post.  Yes the chatter post does appear when created via the email service, but no notifications.

Anyone know why when a chatter post is created via an email service the Email notifications fail to send?

Answer (score 2):

sadly this looks to be an issue with Chatter..

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ktUTAAY

Comment: Wow that is unfortunate.  Esp considering you can post so easily w flows and process builder now.